# How to send BIGPKT using SSH command

Tags: ssh

I need to test common criteria requirement for my SSH clients. As part of that i need to send larger packets from SSH client. Is there ssh option to do so  ? This is the requirements

```
    FCS_SSHC_EXT.1.3The  TSF  shall  ensure  that,  as described  in  RFC  4253,  
packets  greater than [assignment: number of bytes]bytes in  an SSH transport  connection  are dropped.
```

Comment: It is possible, you need to develop a tool to do that. Develop your own tool because if you use a common library (like openssh) it will be good implemented according to the RFC and will not allow to send large packets... I have solved this test in the following link https://unam.re/blog/sending-large-packets-ssh

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe OpenSSH provides an option to control packet size.  A normal SSH client would send different amounts of data depending on how much data there was to read or write at the time, so using a normal SSH client wouldn't be a good way to test this.  You'd probably want to craft a custom tool to test this case, so if you are testing clients, you'd want to craft a custom server.

Note that as far as I'm aware, RFC 4253 doesn't require that packets over the maximum size are dropped.  In fact, it says, “Implementations SHOULD support longer packets, where they might be needed.”  It does specify that implementations should take care to avoid DoS attacks, but with modern cryptography and the resources of a typical system, an implementation might well be able to process a 1 MiB packet without risk of DoS.

If your goal is to find clients that meet some set of criteria, it may be practically easier to see if someone else has done that work for you.